# Unity CineMachine Camera Blend twitching effect

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my scene I have 2 virtual cameras, 2 playable directors on an empty gameobject each. There are 2 timelines. They are blending cams from 1 to 2 and second timeline do the same thing, but in revers direction. 1 vcam priority set to 10, 2 vcam priority set to 9. I had wrote some code like this:

```
    public void RotateVcam(bool trigger)
{
    if(trigger)
    {
        2vcam.Priority += 2;
        playableDirector1.Play();
    }
    else
    {
        2vcam.Priority -= 2;
        playableDirector2.Play();
    }
}
```

Needed timeline is playing, camera is rotating, BUT, after successfull rotation camera is doing some twitching.

Why they are there? How can I manage smooth blend without this strange twitching?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. It was easier to do this task with standard Unity API.

Make quaternion by:

```cs
Quaternion q = new Quaternion.Euler(0,0,0);
```

And then:

```cs
Transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, q, Time.deltaTime * speed);
```